# Wrong versions of jar when dockerize - Tomcat

Tags: docker, tomcat, docker-compose, classpath, pentaho

I have a Java application that use Apache POI as dependency and also other jars, all managed by maven, and is deployed on a Tomcat server that has an old version of Apache POI and also its dependencies. My problem is, when I test the application locally it use the jars that are inside the application, the new version, when I run in a docker container it use the jars that are on the Tomcat server, the old version. How can I fix the application to run and use its jar internally and not externally when are on a docker container? I already used the shad maven plugin but it's hard because there are many jars that are old on the server, I can't shade everything.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the plugin to generate jar from maven shade to maven assembly:

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

In this way the application has everything that needs inside the jar and don't use old classes from the server. And also don't need to shade all the jars.